# Moving a frame half of the parent's size moves it all the way across (Coordinates doubled)?

Tags: ios, objective-c

I have no idea what is going on.

I am not doing anything special.

I have a UIViewController that I create programmatically, no storyboard.

Then I create a UIView with nothing special

```
#import "SettingsView.h"
@interface SettingsView()
@property UIImageView* bg;
@end
@implementation SettingsView

- (id)initWithFrame:(CGRect)frame
{
    self = [super initWithFrame:frame];
    if (self) {
        // Initialization code
        self.bg = [[UIImageView alloc]initWithImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"happy.png"]];
        [self addSubview:self.bg];
    }
    return self;
}

-(void)layoutSubviews
{
    self.bg.frame = self.frame;
}

/*
// Only override drawRect: if you perform custom drawing.
// An empty implementation adversely affects performance during animation.
- (void)drawRect:(CGRect)rect
{
    // Drawing code
}
*/

@end
```

I instantiate it in the VC and when I want to show it I do:

```
-(void)showSettingsView
{
    self.settings.frame = self.view.frame;
    self.btnInfo.userInteractionEnabled = NO;
    self.btnPause.userInteractionEnabled = NO;
    self.btnSettings.userInteractionEnabled = NO;
    self.view.userInteractionEnabled = NO;
    [self.view addSubview:self.settings];
    CGRect frame = self.settings.frame;
    frame.origin.x = frame.size.width * 0.48;
    frame.origin.y = 0;
    self.settings.frame = frame;
}
```

Instead of seeing the image view roughly half way on the screen, it starts at exactly double (0.48 * 2 = 96%) of the screen.

I cannot understand why coordinates are doubled or something?

When I check the frame, I clearly see the origin at around 150 which is half the width of the iPhone.

What could be happening?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Could it be that in...

```
-(void)layoutSubviews
{
    self.bg.frame = self.frame;
}
```

you should be using **bounds** instead of **frame** of your *self* object...

```
-(void)layoutSubviews
{
    self.bg.frame = self.bounds;
}
```

Comment: Glad I could help! I've done that many times myself. Remember to mark this as the answer if it works for you.

Comment: Yeah, unfortunately SO forces me to wait almost half an hour before I can accept it, sorry.